# ¿Qué tipo de lenguaje están usando en este código?

Tags: javascript, eventos, framework7

Saque el código del inspector de google; **su archivo es js**; pero yo programo en JavaScript y nunca e programado de esa forma,**Soy novato en javascript** por eso pregunto si talvez, están usando algún framework de js.  hay un efecto en una pagina web que me gustaría aprender y cuando entre al inspector a leer el código js, me encontré con este tipo de código; aquí muestro un pedazo del código.

**Me gustaría saber en especial esta parte: l = i.xPercent**,tiene un parecido a decir
**m = e.pageY**, esto usaba cuando programava con eventos.
**!GRACIAS...**

```js
bq = function(r, t) {
                    var $, e, a, n, o, i = t || this, l = i.xPercent, s = i.yPercent, p = i.x, A = i.y, _ = i.rotation, v = i.skewX, I = i.skewY, Q = i.scaleX, c = i.scaleY, d = i.target, f = i.xOrigin, m = i.yOrigin, g = i.xOffset, u = i.yOffset, h = i.forceCSS, x = parseFloat(p), P = parseFloat(A);
                    _ = parseFloat(_),
                    v = parseFloat(v),
                    (I = parseFloat(I)) && (v += I = parseFloat(I),
                    _ += I),
                    _ || v ? (_ *= Wc,
                    v *= Wc,
                    $ = Math.cos(_) * Q,
                    e = Math.sin(_) * Q,
                    a = Math.sin(_ - v) * -c,
                    n = Math.cos(_ - v) * c,
                    v && (I *= Wc,
                    o = Math.tan(v - I),
                    a *= o = Math.sqrt(1 + o * o),
                    n *= o,
                    I && (o = Math.tan(I),
                    $ *= o = Math.sqrt(1 + o * o),
                    e *= o)),
                    $ = pa($),
                    e = pa(e),
                    a = pa(a),
                    n = pa(n)) : ($ = Q,
                    n = c,
                    e = a = 0),
                    (x && !~(p + "").indexOf("px") || P && !~(A + "").indexOf("px")) && (x = tc(d, "x", p, "px"),
                    P = tc(d, "y", A, "px")),
                    (f || m || g || u) && (x = pa(x + f - (f * $ + m * a) + g),
                    P = pa(P + m - (f * e + m * n) + u)),
                    (l || s) && (o = d.getBBox(),
                    x = pa(x + l / 100 * o.width),
                    P = pa(P + s / 100 * o.height)),
                    o = "matrix(" + $ + "," + e + "," + a + "," + n + "," + x + "," + P + ")",
                    d.setAttribute("transform", o),
                    h && (d.style[fb] = o)
                }
                ,
                cq = function(r, t, $, e, a, n) {
                    var o, i, l = Ea(a), s = parseFloat(a) * (l && ~a.indexOf("rad") ? rc : 1), p = n ? s * n : s - e, A = e + p + "deg";
                    return l && ("short" === (o = a.split("_")[1]) && (p %= 360) != p % 180 && (p += p < 0 ? 360 : -360),
                    "cw" === o && p < 0 ? p = (p + 36e9) % 360 - 360 * ~~(p / 360) : "ccw" === o && p > 0 && (p = (p - 36e9) % 360 - 360 * ~~(p / 360))),
                    r._pt = i = new Ia(r._pt,t,$,e,p,Qp),
                    i.e = A,
                    i.u = "deg",
                    r._props.push($),
                    i
                }
                ,
                dq = function(r, t, $) {
                    var e, a, n, o, i, l, s, p = Pe.style, A = $._gsap;
                    for (a in p.cssText = getComputedStyle($).cssText + ";position:absolute;display:block;",
                    p[fb] = t,
                    Fb.body.appendChild(Pe),
                    e = Te(Pe, 1),
                    Tb)
                        (n = A[a]) !== (o = e[a]) && "perspective,force3D,transformOrigin,svgOrigin".indexOf(a) < 0 && (i = tb(n) !== (s = tb(o)) ? tc($, a, n, s) : parseFloat(n),
                        l = parseFloat(o),
                        r._pt = new Ia(r._pt,A,a,i,l - i,ok),
                        r._pt.u = s || 0,
                        r._props.push(a));
                    Fb.body.removeChild(Pe)
                }
                ,
                Na("padding,margin,Width,Radius", function(r, t) {
                    var $ = "Top"
                      , e = "Right"
                      , a = "Bottom"
                      , n = "Left"
                      , o = (t < 3 ? [$, e, a, n] : [$ + n, $ + e, a + e, a + n]).map(function($) {
                        return t < 2 ? r + $ : "border" + $ + r
                    });
                    Se[t > 1 ? "border" + r : r] = function(r, t, $, e, a) {
                        var n, i;
                        if (arguments.length < 4)
                            return n = o.map(function(t) {
                                return Kd(r, t, $)
                            }),
                            5 === (i = n.join(" ")).split(n[0]).length ? n[0] : i;
                        n = (e + "").split(" "),
                        i = {},
                        o.forEach(function(r, t) {
                            return i[r] = n[t] = n[t] || n[(t - 1) / 2 | 0]
                        }),
                        r.init(t, i, a)
                    }
                }),
```

Comment: es... javascript... no hay nada raro en ese codigo, salvo un monton de calculos matematicos para calcular algun efecto (como decis)...

Comment: Es Javascript 100%

Comment: Lo que digo es que no creo que sea muy practico programar usando tantas variable y con todas esas operaciones lógicas.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no aporta nada a la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es JavaScript Vanilla, el i.xPercent se utiliza para posicionamiento en Canvas por ejemplo..
Pero en respuesta a tu pregunta: Es JavaScript Puro, ni muy moderno... No usan arrows, usan var, no usan for of y la mayoría son métodos bastante comunes.

Comment: Se puede llegar a programar usando tantas variables y lógica, sin perderse?

Comment: !gracias por la idea, al parecer si están usando % para posicionar.

Comment: Muchas veces llevan junto con el desarrollo una documentación, así como también criterios internos para nombres, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Cómo intuyes, es javascript.

Cómo puedes notar, cualquier persona tiene acceso al código fuente.

Lo que ves es código ofuscado.

La ofuscación es un proceso mediante el cual se reemplazan los símbolos (variables, funciones, etc) por nombres aleatorios, haciéndolo ilegible sin alterar su funcionamiento.

Es una práctica que ocurre en muchos lenguajes, en especial aquellos interpretados. Puesto que en los compilados el código se convierte en instrucciones que el procesador puede entender pero muy difíciles para que una persona lo haga.

Puedes deducir que quién hizo ese código, no quería que nadie lo entienda. Aunque con mucha paciencia y tiempo, podrías descifrarlo.

Como dato extra, otra manera de hacer el código más difícil de leer consiste en reducirlo a una sola línea en lenguajes que lo admitan. Esta se suele combinar también con la ofuscación.

Comment: No sabia de la ofuscación de código para evitar ingeniería inversa. !gracias por el dato...